# PHP- how do i get all first number of comma separated value

Tags: php

for example i have this input in my form 12345,6789,1011
and i want to get their first number the output should be like this 1 6 1 just want to get all the first number of separated comma in my code all I'm getting is the first part of the number 12345 = 1 couldn't get the other number that is separated by comma,
thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: explode() would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
<?php
$string = "12345,6789,1011";
$result = explode(",",$string);
$ConcatString = '';
foreach($result as $Values)
{
    $ConcatString .= $Values[0]." ";
}
echo $ConcatString;
?>
```

Output will be 1 6 1